# Error => invalid address, on passing arguments to function

Tags: solidity, javascript

so I created a function but then I needed to make it dynamic so that I will be able to call the same function body just bypassing the arguments on click of a button 
I am fetching the values from HTML and can view them on the console

```
<button type="button" value="Bet" class="btn-primary" id="player1">
      Player 1 Bet </button>

<button type="button" value="Bet" class="btn-primary" id="player2" >
      Player 2 Bet </button>
```

app.js

```
function ready(){
document.getElementById("bet").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var fromAddress1 = document.querySelector("#bet #fromAddress1").value;

    var fromAddress2 = document.querySelector("#bet #fromAddress2").value;

    console.log(fromAddress1) ----->> THIS WORKS i can fetch address

OraclizeContract.deployed().then(function(instance, fromAddressX) {
  console.log(fromAddressX)  -------------------->>UNDEFINED
  console.log("Initializing");
  instance.deposit({from: fromAddressX,
                    gas: 3000000,
                    value: web3.toWei(betAmount, 'ether')}) //betAmount is a input box and fetching its value into betamount variable and passing it over here
                               .then(function(v){
                                       console.log(v);
                                       console.log("Function Executed");

                                 });
                       }).then(function() {
                                              console.log("Testing");
                       }).catch(function(e) {
                                               console.log(e);
                       });


console.log(fromAddress2); ------------>>>>WORKS
document.getElementById("player2").addEventListener("click", function(e, fromAddress2){

  });
  document.getElementById("player1").addEventListener("click", function(e, fromAddress1){

  });

}) -->> ending event listener

} -->> ending ready function
```

HTML FILE

```
  <form id="bet">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Player 1 - From address:</label>
            <input type=" type" class="form-control" id="fromAddress1">
          </div>
```

As you can see before passing the variable, if I print on the console it displays the correct address
But inside the function it prints undefined
My code already has default account setup, so I am confused about how to mitigate this issue 
I think I am not passing the arguments correctly
Any help is highly appreciated
Thank you

Comment: What is `fromAddress2`? Where is it defined? Where it is initialized? This is broken code!

Comment: Trying to keep it short, fromAddress2 is a variable which is fetching the value which will be entered in the input box

Comment: the function is not receiving the argument,but dont know why